# How can i Change the frame of uialertaction in uialertcontroller in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uialertcontroller, uialertaction

I am adding the `alertView` in whole application. and i want to  change the size of ok or cancel button in  `alertView` so that i can set the  small image of actions.

Anyone please help me for this.

Comment: Post your code, please.

Answer (score 0):

You can not change the size of `ok` or `cancel` button in  `alertView`.

The only solution that I could figure is to make a custom view with `UIVisualEffect` and show it like `UIActionSheet`

Welcome if other solution is there :)

if you want to do this for adding image, then try following way:

```
UIAlertController * view=   [UIAlertController
                             alertControllerWithTitle:@"Add Image"
                             message:@"Image Added successfully"
                             preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet];


UIAlertAction* add = [UIAlertAction
                     actionWithTitle:@"add"
                     style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                     handler:^(UIAlertAction * action)
                     {
                         //Do some thing here
                         [view dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

                     }];
[add setValue:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"add.png"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal] forKey:@"image"];
[view addAction:add];
[self presentViewController:view animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change the frame of default Alert view for this you have to use custom alert view. Please refer the below links for custom alert views

1. https://github.com/dogo/SCLAlertView
2. https://github.com/vikmeup/SCLAlertView-Swift (Swift)
3. https://github.com/mtonio91/AMSmoothAlert